# Regarding sql queryformation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one DB table which contains Payment(Merchant,Transaction,TimeStamp).where for teach transaction we can have multiple merchants. Now i want to form a query where for transaction in (val1, val2, val3) , we will get the merchant who did latest transaction.eg:

```
Merchant   Transaction    Time
----------------------------------
M1           T1            t1
M2           T1            t2
M1           T1             t3
M3           T2            t4
M4           T2            t5
M5           T3            t6
```

so in case where transactionid in (T1,T2.T3) , we will get M1 (since M1 did latest T1 transaction on time t3),M4,M5 `(t1<t2 timestamp)`

Comment: What about a `ORDER BY` clause? see here: [order by](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp)

Comment: try using this query "SELECT Merchant,Transaction,TimeStamp FROM Payment GRUOP BY Transaction ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Merchant FROM DB_TABLE WHERE transaction IN(T1, T2, T3) ORDER
BY Time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Payment
group by transaction
order by Time desc;
```

Comment: but i want the topmost tuple of all group values got. Not all tuples of a group

Comment: You mean that for all transaction you need just the value for one merchant?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT p.Merchant
FROM Payment p
JOIN 
(SELECT Merchant, Transaction, MAX(Time) as time 
    FROM Payment GROUP BY Merchant, Transaction) t
ON (p.Merchant = t.Merchant AND p.Transaction = t.Transaction AND p.Time = t.time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Last() function to get last row after separating all transection.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp

Answer (score 1):

The SQL statement you are looking for is the following:

```
SELECT p.Merchant, p.Transaction, p.Time
FROM Payment p
JOIN 
(SELECT Transaction, MAX(Time) as time 
    FROM Payment 
    WHERE Transaction IN('T1', 'T2', 'T3')
    GROUP BY Transaction) t
ON (p.Transaction = t.Transaction AND p.Time = t.time)
```

Checkout this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/defbc/7) for the result according to your example.